# Connecting App Store release app to Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, mac-appstore

I am trying to connect an App Store released app to Xcode.

The reason I want to do this is because I want to check attribution data from Appsflyer and make sure that it is sending partner data that we can use for internal tracking purposes.

When I use Xcode to generate a build for my device, it only lists it as organic tracking, so I need to use a release version that has gone through the proper attribution method (i.e. clicking a link that leads through Appsflyer).

Is there anyway to get the print logs from an installed (from the App  Store) app via Xcode or some other way? I.e. a way to attach the process to Xcode? I looked in the Attach to Process part of Xcode but didn't see the process anywhere.

Comment: Try `Activity Monitor` > double-click the process > `Open files and ports` tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the device logs using Console. In Console.app, connected iOS devices appear in the sidebar and selecting a device brings up the system log in real time.

To use Xcode to attach to the process, choose Debug → ‘Attach to Process by PID or Name’ and enter the name of the app. See [Attach debugger to iOS app after launch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9721830/1549818) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't actually think this is a solution. The link provided seems to provide a way to attach to a development version of the app. I want to attach to a production version as I am testing attribution campaign data.